# iOS 15 Beta 2 - WKWebView - Web socket server not receives large Message (2MB)

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, websocket, wkwebview

I have Xcode (iOS) application which has WebSocket communication between Xcode based c++ library and WKWebView (Java script) front end UI. client (c++) usually sends 200 bytes. however on demand, it may send upto 2MB encrypted binary data. In iOS 14, server (Java script) was able to receive all messages including 2 MB of binary message. After upgrading the  iOS 15 Beta 2, websocket.onmessage callback method being called when it receive message data upto 500 KB. when the server sends message size beyond 500 KB,  not received websocket.onmessage callback method. Do I need to tune any xcode properties to receive 2 MB data ? , is there any relation between this issue and com.apple.developer.kernel.increased-memory-limit entitlements

```
websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
}
```